# Connect DB class in more file

Tags: php, database, class, pdo

Goodmorning everyone.
I have 3 files: config_db.php, module.php and index.php
I need db connection to hold for many module.php.

so I would like on index to call the class of module.php and the module.php to call config_db.
I give a practical example:

**index.php**:

```
require_once('../component/command/module.php');
$boards= new command();
$result = $boards->getAllOutputs();
```

**module.php:**

```
class command extends DB {
    protected static $database = 'db';

    function getAllOutputs() {
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM outputs";
        $db = Main::getInstance();
        $obj = $db->fetch_single_row($sql, $data);
        
        var_dump($obj);
    }
}
```

**config_db.php:**

```
    abstract class DB
    {
    
        protected static $instance;
    
        protected $db;
    
        protected static $host = 'localhost';
        protected static $user = 'root';
        protected static $pass = 'pw';
        protected static $database='database';
    
        public static function getInstance()
        {
            if (!isset(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new static();
    
            return self::$instance;
        }
    
        protected function __construct()
        {
            $this->db = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', static::$host, static::$database), static::$user, static::$pass);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    
        public static function db()
        {
            return static::getInstance()->db;
        }
    
        public function fetch_single_row($sql, $data)
        {
            if( $data !== null )
                $data = array_values( $data ); // Incase it's an associative array
            $sel = self::db()->prepare( $sql );
            $sel->execute( $data );
            $sel->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
            $obj = $sel->fetch();
            return $obj;
        }
    }
```

when opening the index the error is the following:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to protected DB::__construct() from invalid context in C:\wamp64\www\xxx\tmpl\index.php on line 706

> ( ! ) Error: Call to protected DB::__construct() from invalid context in C:\wamp64\www\xxx\tmpl\index.php on line 706

could you help me?

Comment: Not sure which line 706 is, but in `Main::getInstance();`, what is `Main` defined as?

Comment: `protected function __construct()` seems the problem. Docu says all magic methods must be public. https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: sorry line 706 is the line in index.php where i insert $boards= new command();

Comment: BTW: what @NigelRen mentioned - Main shoud be `self::getInstance()`, since you extended the `DB` class

Comment: @cotton i try to move protected to public but the error now move like this: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'db' in C:\wamp64\www\acquario\core\config_db.php on line 25
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'db' in C:\wamp64\www\acquario\core\config_db.php on line 25 ............line 25 is  $this->db = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', static::$host, static::$database), static::$user, static::$pass);

Comment: @RobertaOnnis From the error message i see you started using PDO (good). 
_The above code may not be the same anymore. This will make it not easy to help._
But `Unknown database 'db'` comes from the property `protected static $database = 'db';` in the `command` class.
There is no database with the name `db`.
This could mean: 1. you connected to a different mysql server, or 2. the database name is just wrong.
BTW: (no offence) if you get a error message, just read it. If you dont understand it then just google the exact error. Very often you find the solution in seconds.